# Magento 2 folder/file permissions

Tags: magento2, permissions

I suspect that the permissions might have gotten messed up on my Magento 2 installation. On the old versions I would run the following command to make folders 755 and files 644:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod -c 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod -c 755 {} \;
```

Can you please let me know what the correct file and folder permissions are for Magento 2 since they seem to be different? Also, if there are some particular folders or files that would need different permissions.

Comment: Try 777 Permission before that take backup

Comment: My server's PHP handler is suPHP and I don't really want to assign 777 to everything since that would practically open my website to anyone. Are there more specific permissions that can be assigned?

Comment: Magento have the file permission on folders to 775 and for the files permission set to 644

Comment: FYI, if magento 2 is in a "home" directory, `var/cache` and `pub/static` need suid bits set. I used: 
`find var/cache  -type d -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 1775`

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You can refer http://devdocs.magento.com/

The important things:

- The owner of the Magento file system:
  Must have full control (read/write/execute) of all files and directories.
- Must not be the webserver user; it should be a different user.
- The web server user must have write access to the following files and directories:

  - var
  - app/etc
  - pub
  - (and probably new in 2.2.1:) generated
- In addition, the web server's group must own the Magento file system so that the Magento user (who is in the group) can share access to files with the web server user. (This includes files created by the Magento Admin or other web-based utilities.)
- We recommend setting the permissions as follows:

  - All directories have 770 permissions.
  - 770 permissions give full control (that is, read/write/execute) to the owner and to the group and no permissions to anyone else.
  - All files have 660 permissions.
  - 660 permissions mean the owner and the group can read and write but other users have no permissions.

You should set it as below:

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

// 644 permission for files
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
                   
// 755 permission for directory
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;    

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: It only works for me with `\;`, e.g.: `find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

Comment: the issue here will be `chown`   not   `chmod` proper user with suPHP is the most important :)

Comment: But this is for development mode. For production it should be group-readonly - no idea how that should work

Comment: I think you also need `chmod u+x bin/magento` to be able to execute console commands.

Comment: friends don't let friends 777

Comment: I have apache, ec2-user and jenkins user. How I can set permissions for /var/www/site? Your variant isn't working for 3 users. Thanks.

Comment: I always use the find variante with `+`, as in `find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +;` and it runs MUCH faster. I never see this referenced though is that wrong?

Comment: app/etc 777> Haha nice. Hackable easy. app/etc contains your db information

Comment: @SwAt.Be There's a .htaccess file in the app folder with `Deny from all`, so why would this be a security concern? The web server user must be able to read this file anyway. Edit: On shared hosting I agree though

Comment: @MilanSimek Well it depends much on how your internal permissions are set. Your app/etc directory should NEVER have 777 permissions. Only your user that actually does the connection should have permissions to that fille. Otherwise this can be a breach easily

Comment: What about windows 7, how can i give above all commands to windows?

Comment: I am uncertain if the answer is complete. I see some comments about chmod 777. So is the above answer correct? or should it be adapted?

Comment: You said files should have `660` yet we set `644` to files? Why?

Comment: chmod: changing permissions of './var/log/system.log': Operation not permitted

Answer (score 23):

In some rare cases, you can't use 770 and 660, like @MagenX says, 755 and 644 could also be the permission you need. (Some Fast-CGI users I guess)

So in that case, you run:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

That seems to fix it, but if Magento generates new files or directories, those will have the permission 770 and 660 again. You can edit those default chmod values in the following files:

```
/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/DriverInterface.php 
(WRITEABLE_DIRECTORY_MODE and WRITEABLE_FILE_MODE)

/lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php 
(directory_mode and file_mode)
```

After these changes, run the first command again and after that, newly generated files shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Note: Editing files like this is never a good idea, but I suspect these chmod options are going to be configurable in the future, so I took the easy way.

Comment: Cant find /lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php on M231

Comment: @snh_nl In newer Magento version, they don't set the permission anymore if they do, it looks like they use 775.

After a fresh installation you can just run:
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chmod u+x bin/magento

In the root and you should be fine.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the method like the [Magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html) recommends:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: How to give write permission to generated folder in windows? @Rafael Corrêa Gomes

Answer (score 9):

If you are using SELinux ̣(e.g. CentOS) try:

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t var
```

(from magento root folder of course)

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

For local development
set `pub` and `var` to 775 or 777

Comment: why? (There is minimum to a comment length)

Comment: Why do unknown users need access to pub or cache??

Answer (score 7):

In Magento Community recommend

We recommend setting the permissions as follows:

All **directories** have **770** permissions.
770 permissions give full control (that is, read/write/execute) to the owner and to the group and no permissions to anyone else.

All **files** have **660** permissions.
660 permissions mean the owner and the group can read and write but other users have no permissions.

For more ref this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 5):

no special permissions, you just make sure that files owned by user who runs php or in case of cPanel - cpanel user, and same group

so your command is good:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod -c 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod -c 755 {} \;
```

just update files owner:

```
chown -R user:user *
```

where `user` is the owner, `user` who runs php.

instead of changing permissions everytime, login / work as proper user, files owner, from root to user:

```
cd /magento/root/folder/
su $(stat -c '%U' index.php) -s /bin/bash
whoami
pwd
```

Comment: How to give write permission  to generated folder in windows? @MagenX

Answer (score 5):

Similar issue also for sharing hosting:
[Magento 2: Recommended File Permission for shared hosting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99703/magento-2-recommended-file-permission-for-shared-hosting)

devdocs magento for permisions:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html
and for prod:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Answer (score 5):

Put this content inside your root folder, then execute it with the console.

Dont forget to `chmod +x yourfile.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
chmod 2775 -R .

chmod 777 -R ./pub/

chmod 777 -R ./var/
```

Comment: how can i put this code ? as htacces or php file

Comment: Avoid this, it's basically making your webserver directory open to the public. instead read the devdocs provided by magento to properly secure the version your running.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \;
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
chmod 700 includes
chmod 600 includes/config.php
```

Also detailed information is available on, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: Question calls for advise on Magento 2

Answer (score 4):

Execute these commands as a root user. If you have already given 777 permission revert it using first two commands else proceed with the rest.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +

find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
```

Set the ownership to Magento user and web user  using

```
sudo chown -R <Magento user>:<web server group> .
```

Running these commands sets the permission for folders and files in Magento root and for the new files to be created in var, pub and generated directories.

Don't run any command as **root user** as it might cause the new **static files** to be created with root ownership which might prevent web user to access such files forcing you to provide 777 permission.Please at any case don't give 777 permission if so please revert it back.So run Magento commands as **Magento user**.

Comment: For the production mode, what are all the recommended permission https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/323247/57334

Answer (score 0):

i solved in this way for CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 on Plesk Onyx 17.8.11

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; &&  find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && chmod 777 ./app/etc  && chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .
```

Comment: You should avoid using 777 on files and directories. It opens your shop to unnecessary security risk. Instead, read the docs provided by magento for the version your running.

Answer (score 0):

If you face any issue like 500 internal server error then you need to check the following things:

1. First, you need to check your server log, and if you find and error then first try to solve that.
2. Check your `.htaccess` file.
3. Please check your `index.php` file permission.
   If it's `0664` then Change `index.php` file permissions from `0664` to `0644`
4. Check your file and folder permissions. Make sure it's proper as per the Magento 2 requirement.

I Hope, this information helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's file ownership and not file permissions I find.

File permissions I use:

```
find . -type f \-exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d \-exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find . -type f -name "*.php" \-exec chmod 600 {} \;
chmod 600 app/etc/*.xml
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Different hosts though may have slightly different specs, first lines file permission 664 and 775 may be fine too. Avoid 777/666 like the plague! Lines 3 and 4 tighten it up a little.

Check what user:group owns the files, run on the folder containing the magento installation:

```
ls -la
```

results will show you file permissions, user and group along with other info, including the user and group of the magento installation folder itself (file listed as . at the top).

Use below to change the user:group as required (if in doubt, consult host):

```
chown -R user:group .
```

As others have said, refer to your Magento versions documentation.

If you still problems, you are likely going to need to consult your host, the tracing goes on deep, run below in the Magento install folder which checks which user is running apache processes, if you've got this far, it's likely to give you a clue and your host if something's out

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Usually its the same user as the folder above magento's install, but at this stage it's really hosting environment dependant, dig into stack exchange https://serverfault.com/! I've had sleepless nights on Magento 2 permissions and ownership, hate it, I do hope they introduce a more friendly solution to this persistent problem not common on many other platforms.