# Centos and Magento 2.0 problem

Tags: magento-2.0, setup

I want to install Magento 2.0 on a server with Centos system. My problem is after installation the Admin Panel is look like in this image:

[image: admin panel error]

In the firebug console I have a lot of 404 errors:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/print.css"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://example.com/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js"
>
> ReferenceError: require is not defined

I try to see what permissions are int hat folder `pub/static/` with a ftp client and there are **770**, so with my ftp user I get there permissions denied. I try to use:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

but nothing happend.

How I can solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 has extensive documentation of the installation process. See here for post-installation verification and troubleshooting: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/verify.html

In particular, your problem sounds like the exact problem detailed here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_no-styles.html

This could be caused by rewrites not working, or by incorrect file permissions. Broken rewrites could be a result of apache being configured with `AllowOverride None`, or some such, preventing Magento's `.htaccess` from executing. (I would expect that to also break the admin URL, though, so may not be that.)

Permissions setup is detailed here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#instgde-prereq-compose-access

In particular, given SSH access:

**File system permissions and ownership** (per official M2 documentation)

1. Change to the Magento installation directory:

   `cd <web server docroot>/<magento2 base dir>`
2. Set ownership:

   `chown -R :<your web server group name> .`

   Typical examples:

   CentOS: `chown -R :apache .`
   Ubuntu: `chown -R :www-data .`
3. Set permissions:

   `find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento`

   If you must enter the commands as sudo, use:

   `sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento`

Comment: thank you for your answer, i try to use this permissions but i have this error now: NetworkError: 403 Forbidden

Comment: You can enable [developer mode](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#config-mode) to see errors in the browser, you can try curling the URL to see if there's a more informative response header, or you can look in your web server logs.

Please post any error messages here.

Comment: Hi thank you, i see now the admin url is something like this, i think is not correct: www.example.co/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/d1c029ca7481152a590e40d909a8604e5bcc470876886227b13aa98368b97be6/

Comment: @RobertD that admin URL appears correct.

Comment: i try everything, i reinstall the server again, the problem is still there, any idea what i can try? or how I can find what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running in production mode and forgot to run:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new for this kind of installation. I got this problem, too. I can resolve by run this command:

```
/var/www/html/magento2$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I also face with accessing the admin page, which I can resolve by editing apache configuration file : vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf as:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My system environment:
- CentOS v7.1
- Apache v2.4.6
- PHP v5.6.24
- MySQL 5.6.31