# Magento 2 developer mode doesn't regenerate static files automatically

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

I have a Magento 2.0.2 installation in developer mode and I still can't figure out how to force it to regenerate the static view files whenever I make a change in my CSS.

I verified that I am in developer mode by running 
`php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

On [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html) it says that developer mode disables static view files caching, but that is not the case for me.

I tried to edit the `di.xml` as mentionned in [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95991/local-installation-of-magento-2-doest-not-generate-files-in-the-pub-static-folde) but it didn't change Magento's behavior.

How can I tell magento to automatically regenerate static view files?

Answer (score 5):

In developer mode, M2 does not generate static files. It should create symlinks to them from the various modules. If you however have ran setup:static-content:deploy and have those files in place, it won't update them. Try removing all static files and see if Magento links to them (be careful not to remove the actual files if you have symlinks)

Comment: I tried deleting the whole content of pub/static (without deleting the .htaccess file) and it didn't work. It looks like the old files were regenerated.

Comment: Currently, the only way I'm able to get the updated content is by clicking 'Flush Static Files Cache' in the Magento Cache Management page.

Comment: I had the same problem of symlinks not being generated in developer mode; then I realized I had deleted the `.htacces` file from `pub/static`; once I restored the `.htaccess` file in `pub/static` the next request regenerated all symlinks; hope it helps.

Comment: I have the same problem currently with Magento 2.0.6. Tried re-adding the `.htaccess`-file (I run nginx, so I didn't think it would do much), and as expected, it didn't work. Previously my symlinks were created, but now not anymore ...

Comment: As we thought `pub/static` is autogenerated anyways we also deleted it manually at one point and ran into the same problem. Looks like in our apache2/php7 setup the now missing .htaccess file is really responsible for this. After recreating the original .htaccess developer mode was working fine again. Here the link to the recent .htacces: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess

Comment: Deleting from `static` folder manually also didn't help. Only flush static content from admin works. I confirm I have enabled dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me. After moving the site to another server, it turned out I didn't set the file permissions correct.

I ran `find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento` and that solved my problem.

More info: [Magento 2: Recommended File Permission for shared hosting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99703/magento-2-recommended-file-permission-for-shared-hosting)

Update: make sure the pub folder (magento/pub) and the underlying folders have read and write permissions.

Comment: Whomever downvoted: why?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. I had `developer` mode enabled for some time, then for some reason (likely an error on my part at some point), it no longer seemed to work.

Simple solution for me was to reset the mode to developer again:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

NB: You might need to set it to `default` and then `developer`.

Comment: This also didn't help. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with my less updates noting showing unless I flushed my static files. The fix for me was to disable `mod_expires`. This was caching the css and etc.

Inside of the `pub/static/.htaccess` file you will should have something like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresActive On

    # Data
    <FilesMatch \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/csv "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/zip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-bzip2 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # CSS, JavaScript, html
    <FilesMatch \.(css|js|html|json)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 year"

    # Favicon, images, flash
    <FilesMatch \.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|swf|svg)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"

    # Fonts
    <FilesMatch \.(eot|ttf|otf|svg|woff|woff2)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

By disabling `mod_expires` or commenting out the above and doing a hard refresh in your browser (Mac Users hold down `Shift + Command + r`) your changes should start showing each time you make them.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue too!

It turns out in my case it was a permission issue.

```
cat /etc/apache2/logs/error_log | grep static
```

and

```
tail -f /etc/apache2/logs/error_log | grep static
```

gave me interesting info (maybe your log file might be named differently)

first I saw:

```
[Wed Oct 30 12:19:34.287356 2019] [core:crit] [pid 27633] (13)Permission denied: [client 24.48.87.7:16680] AH00529: /home/[datuser]/public_html/pub/static/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/[datuser]/public_html/pub/static/' is executable
```

it turned out my `pub/static` folder was not executable. Then after fixing that I got

```
[Wed Oct 30 12:22:46.490759 2019] [:error] [pid 27290] [client ipremoved] SoftException in Application.cpp:267: File "/home/[datuser]/public_html/pub/static.php" is writeable by group, referer: [url removed]
[Wed Oct 30 12:22:46.490961 2019] [core:error] [pid 27290] [client ipremoved] End of script output before headers: static.php, referer: [url removed]
```

On our server apache cant serve files that are writable by group for some reason, some Cpanel security stuff I believe. So I had to set `644` on all files under `pub` and finally my symlinks started to get created!!