# CSS and JS not loading from Extension Error 403

Tags: extensions, javascript, css, magento-2.1

after installing a slider extension I can't get it to display properly in the frontend. There are just the pictures and text without any formatting or functionality. It is correctly configured, but loading the css/js files fails (Error 403 in browser console). I checked the directory. The files are there and permissions are 755/644. I also noticed that in my htaccess file everything in the root folder is redirected to error 403. Does this have anything to do with it?

System:
Magento 2.1,
Plesk 12,
Ubuntu 14.04
Website: http://speedswim.de/

EDIT: Following Error in error_log: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html
Cleared all files in the var/view_preprocessed/ and pub/static/ dirs.

There was something wrong with the extension. I installed a different one and everything is fine now...

Comment: but after first page refresh everything went back to the old problem...

Comment: Error even shows up in error_log when slider is displayed correctly

Answer (score 4):

After install any extension, fire below commands and then flush cache.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And also check your folder have proper permission or not ? You can refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions) link for folder permission.

Comment: I did all of that in exactly this order... Still Access forbidden to css and js. Btw, server is http://speedswim.de/

Comment: Checked permissions vis ssh, but everything as it should be.

Comment: it seems you are using other locale, so fire command as php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE

Comment: did that, still not working

Comment: This has resolved the issue in my case.