# Unable to open front end and admin

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions

When i try to open my site it is not opening, same as my back end as i added the error below.

Adminpanel issue in site.

[image]

Comment: [Previously i am also facing this problem so,please follow this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara : my magento ver 1.9.x,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your magento is unable to read the xml configuration files. Try giving appropriate read permission to all your xml files and try.

```
cd your/magento_root/
find . -type f -name '*.xml' -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: How can i give read permission to my xml file

Comment: Revised my answer, check it

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gfnDd3I.png

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the **magento can't read your xml files**. Check the file permission, remove the cache. 
Make sure your file permissions are set to

> Directories : 755 ::: Files : 644

Comment: how can i check permission and how can i change permission

Comment: Are you using ubuntu or windows ?

Comment: windows only...

Comment: magento version 1.9.2.3,

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjF8q6O7q7PAhWEso8KHYBkCfEQFggdMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc754344(v%3Dws.11).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFbHQymDCd7_h2g5YixO-cSSqHBpQ&bvm=bv.133700528,d.c2I

Comment: which file i change permission

Comment: You can read this for more information http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Answer (score 1):

**Reason 1**

Try clearing cache, and check file permissions are correctly set,

Directories : 755

Files : 644

Else another alternative is Reinstall Magento and do following steps:

It may solve the issue, but suggested to have round of research before doing and surely back up database:

Before to import database : - Add query

```
1) SET SQL_MODE=”NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO”;
```

OR

at beginning of sql import script

After import / installation : - Execute following query

```
2) UPDATE `core_store` SET `store_id` = 0 WHERE `code` like 'admin';
   UPDATE `core_website` SET `website_id` = 0 WHERE `code` like 'admin';
   UPDATE `customer_group` SET `customer_group_id` = 0 WHERE `customer_group_code` like 'NOT LOGGED IN';
```

**Reason 2**

The problem is the magento can't read your xml files. So check file permission again for xml files and check your xml files under app/etc folder and every custom modules under app/code/local/ may be some xml files are corrupted (miss formed).

**clear cache**

Note:- not given proper permission also occurs this error.

Comment: what is mean Directories : 755

Files : 644

Comment: you can reset all permission please find https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php

Comment: not working. githud code

Comment: how you execute this code?

Comment: just past in rool folder, then execute through url

Comment: still i get same error

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal or connect your website via ssh access and fire below command one by one for `file/directory` permission

```
chmod -R 644 ./*
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod 550 ./mage
```

Comment: could you pls briefly explain, i run in my local host

Comment: your problem is related is file permission so open your terminal and fire above command one by one

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/m6NSZhV.png

Comment: how can i run these commands

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Magento can't read your XML files. So check file permission again for xml files and check your xml files under app/etc folder and every custom modules under app/code/local/ may be some XML files are corrupted (miss formed).

**just run an rsync -p on with your production site**

Can Use cleanup Script  for your localhost
[cleanup script](https://github.com/lalitmohann/Magento)