# magento 2.1.6 installation

Tags: magento-2.1, installation, file-permissions

I have some problem with the installation of magento.
This is the config:

```
Dedicated Server,
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core),
Apache,
Mysql,
Magento CE 2.1.6
```

I have a user named `web` and the web service user is named `apache`:
`$ id web`
**uid=1000(web) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)**
`$ id apache`
**uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)**

I had a permission problem which I will talk about here, so I have given**chmod -R 777** for all files and directories inside my Magento dir.

Also, I have done **chown -R web:apache** for all files and dirs inside my Magento dir.

Now permissions are as follows:

```
drwxrwxrwx.  4 web apache   4096 Apr 22 00:03 app
drwxrwxrwx.  2 web apache     36 Apr 22 00:03 bin
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache 435065 Mar 28 23:07 CHANGELOG.md
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache   1843 Mar 28 23:05 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache 344410 Mar 28 23:07 composer.lock
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache   3381 Mar 28 23:07 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache    631 Mar 28 23:07 COPYING.txt
drwxrwxrwx.  5 web apache     59 Apr 22 00:03 dev
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache   2864 Mar 28 23:07 Gruntfile.js.sample
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache   1368 Mar 28 23:07 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache    315 Mar 28 23:07 ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
drwxrwxrwx.  4 web apache     47 Apr 22 00:03 lib
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache  10376 Mar 28 23:07 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache  10364 Mar 28 23:07 LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache   5071 Mar 28 23:07 nginx.conf.sample
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache   1427 Mar 28 23:07 package.json.sample
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 web apache    814 Mar 28 23:07 php.ini.sample
drwxrwxrwx.  2 web apache     55 Apr 22 00:03 phpserver
drwxrwxrwx.  6 web apache   4096 Apr 22 00:03 pub
drwxrwxrwx.  7 web apache   4096 Apr 22 00:03 setup
drwxrwxrwx.  7 web apache   4096 Apr 22 00:03 update
drwxrwxrwx.  6 web apache     88 Apr 22 19:02 var
drwxrwxrwx. 29 web apache   4096 Apr 22 00:03 vendor
```

Still I get **File Permission Check** Error on installation:

```
File Permission Check
4 file permission not met. Hide detail

The best way to resolve this is to allow write permissions for files in the following Magento directories and subdirectories. The exact fix depends on your server, your host, and other system variables. 
For help, see our File Permission Help or call your hosting provider.

"/var/www/html/zibajooyan/app/etc" - Not writable, change the permissions. Show details
"/var/www/html/zibajooyan/var" - Not writable, change the permissions. Show details
"/var/www/html/zibajooyan/pub/media" - Not writable, change the permissions. Show details
"/var/www/html/zibajooyan/pub/static" - Not writable, change the permissions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Just leaving it here for other folks might possibly encounter this problem:
The problem is with the dots at the end of the permissions.

```
drwxrwxrwx.  6 web apache   4096 Apr 22 00:03 pub
```

It means it has SELinux context which is denying users from accessing it.

For removing it we should:

1. Disable `SELINUX` in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`.
2. `reboot` the server.
3. run `sudo find custom_magento_dir/ -exec setfattr -x security.selinux {} \;` on my custom magento dir.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't disable SELinux, the better solution would be to tell SELinux that those directories should be writeable with the following command:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/dir
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I re-enabled `SELINUX=enforcing` and ran `$ sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/zibajooyan` but nothing access is being denied again. Any idea?

Answer (score -2):

```
 Change the modes of the file hierarchies rooted in the files
 instead of just the files themselves.

       chmod -R 777 *

 ( I think you have missed the symbol '*')
```

---

```
     Let me explain this with your directories
         Trial 1
            CD /var/www/html/zibajooyan
            chmod -R 777 *
--------------------------------------------------------------------
         Trial 2 - if Trial1 does not work

            CD /var/www/html/zibajooyan/app
               chmod -R 777 * 

            CD /var/www/html/zibajooyan/pub
              chmod -R 777 * 

            CD /var/www/html/zibajooyan/media
              chmod -R 777 * 

              ls -l ( check the output for the respective folder's )
---------------------------------------------------------------------
            I hope this works.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean the parent folder (`zibajooyan` in the code above) should have 777 permission too? If so It has but it doesn't work yet. Otherwise please advice.

Comment: Check the edited answer please.

Comment: Thanks for the help my friend. I have done the same thing. I think I've found the problem. Please see my edit.