# Magento 2: modules are not listing in admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, extensions, file-permissions

On my test server, every installed extensions are not listing in admin panel under *Stores* > *Settings* > *Configuration* > *Advanced* > *Advanced*.

And if the extension has configuration parameters `vendorName/moduleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`, module configuration tab is not visible under *Stores* > *Settings* > *Configuration*

Doing `php bin/magento module:status` the modules are listing and they are enabled.

Checking in the database (`setup_module` table) the modules are listing.

Checking in `app/etc/config.xml` the modules are listing and set to '1'.

On my local machine, all works fine so it must be a server issue (permissions ???).

I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Is your local environment in dev mode and production environment in production mode? How is your cache configured?

Comment: I thought they had same configuration but checking it I note you're right.
So I changed mode on my test server: `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`
I tried again but nothing is changed.

Comment: Seems like you missed something in your server. Are you sure you correctly copied all the files, you have correct permissions settiongs and you flushed your cache?

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Using `composer require <modulename>` works fine in Local. But it's not working on Server

Comment: I think is a file permissions issue.
I have web server running with **www-data** user but I execute **php bin/magento** as another user and this setting requires me every time to give write permission to **www-data** user on **var/** dir.

How do you manage users on your production server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to directories/files permissions management, as I thought.

For my test server (in *developer* mode, just for now) I've followed this guide: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95033/10018 to set right permissions.

Then I've used **setgid** on *var/* directory:

```
rm -rf var/*
chgrp www-data var/
chmod g+s var/
```

Now all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add a configuration section for a module using a `system.xml` you need the corresponding ACL.

Example if you have a `system.xml` that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="module" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="140" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <tab>vendor</tab>
            ...
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Then you will need an `etc/acl.xml` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
<resource id="Magento_Backend::system">
                    <resource id="Vendor_Module::vendor" title="Vendor" sortOrder="100">
                        <resource id="Vendor_Module::module" title="Module" sortOrder="100"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: I know that.. the extension has its `etc/acl.xml` file.
The extension works fine installed on another machine

Comment: @WaPoNe did you try to disable it and re enable it again from the CLI ? Is your admin user a superadmin or restricted user ?

Comment: I tried just now.. nothing is changed.
_Is your admin user a superadmin or restricted user ?_ Are you talking about backend user? Superadmin? I'm using admin user, the first one created.

Comment: yeah ok so it's what I call a superadmin. Hmmm that's annoying I'm out of ideas here

Comment: Yeah.. it so very strange.
I tried installing this extension, for example: `composer require wapone/module-stickers`.
It works fine on my local machine but it doesn't work on test server.
Could you try to install it?

The only my idea is about file permissions..

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, PHP's OPCache can cause these symptoms as well. After you ensure permissions are sorted (see WaPoNe's answer), if the problem persists, flush OPCache and then Magento's cache.

To flush OPCache, restart PHP, or create a temporary script on your site and run it from the web:

```
<?php

$reset = opcache_reset();

echo $reset ? 'Flushed OPCache' : 'Failed';
```

cf. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php