# Magento admin-panel isn't working

Tags: backend, installation, admin-panel, magento2.1.5

I wanted to try working with **Magento**, so I downloaded the **Magento 2.1.5** Community version from the website and installed in on my localserver from XAmpp (php 7.0.15). 
Magento installed successfully (after changing some small php things), but after I logged in the adminpanel the buttons (on the left) weren't working and some logo's weren't loaded. I tried different things but they all didn't help. (cleared the cache)

So I tried again to download Magento but this time Magento 2.0.15. Same problem. I even have tried to install both with php 5.6 but then the installation wasn't successful.

So my question is, why isn't it working? and can it be solved easily? (if so, how?)

This are the console errors, it may be usefull:

```
<i> 
require.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
mixins.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/static/version1490356509/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/static/version1490356509/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
requirejs-config.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at requirejs-config.js:58
    at requirejs-config.js:63
    at requirejs-config.js:398
magento-icon.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
(index):39Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):39
(index):87Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):87
(index):286Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):286
(index):418Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):418
(index):463Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):463
(index):504Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):504
(index):527Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):527
(index):550Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):550
opensans-700.woff2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-600.woff2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-400.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
admin-icons.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-600.woff Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-700.woff Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-400.woff Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
admin-icons.woff Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-600.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-700.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-400.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
admin-icons.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
ytheme-magento.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ext-all.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
</i>
```

Comment: Are you using Firefox with the firebug extension per chance?

Answer (score 1):

Open `di.xml` (E.g.: `C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\etc\di.xml`), and edit this line to read "Copy" at the end:

`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>`

Then restart Apache, and refresh your shop admin.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 is a huge application that has a lot of elements that are being built up in the admin using Javascript. What you are describing sounds like the JS assets are still loading. It might seem like the page has loaded, but there are a ton of elements that are loaded in the background (lazy loading). Open up your inspector and look in the network tab (i'm using chrome, but all browsers have the same basic functionality) and you will see that RequireJS is still loading files even though the "page load" is done. I have had times when the admin will take a minute or two to load all the way. After the first load, a lot of the files will be cached in the browser and it will speed up the process of navigating around.

Comment: It even says: `RequreJS - Status: Failed`. I searched for the file and it is there but still it refuses to load.. (or do anything)

Comment: I would second Max's point, look at the file permissions: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions. From there, check to make sure that your xamp install has enough system memory to process that app. Since you have tried a few diff versions of M2, i would assume it's your system and not a code base issue.

Answer (score 0):

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is an error which usually comes up when the site you are trying to visit cannot establish connection with the destination site.

Maybe you can check to see that all your file permissions are set properly. Also verify the files are actually there.