# Magento 2 installation & Linux file folder permission

Tags: magento2, installation, file-permissions, linux

I am using Linux Mint. I installed a quick package of Magento 2 Theme. I tried to browse Admin Panel. But I couldn't browse. Then I found I have to change file & folder permission. I tried below command to change file permission.

`foysal@foysal-laptop /var/www/html/aloquick $ find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

I got below result.

`chmod: changing permissions of './var/generation/Magento/Weee/Model/Tax/Proxy.php': Operation not permitted`

I tried below command to change folder permission.

`foysal@foysal-laptop /var/www/html/aloquick $ find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`

I got below result.

`chmod: changing permissions of './var/generation': Operation not permitted`

Where is the issue ? Am I using wrong commands ?

**UPDATE**

I executed (`sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`) this commands. But I can't browse both front end and back end of the site.

[image]

[image]

Comment: sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

Comment: Thanks @jack. I ran your command but the issue remains as like before.

Answer (score 3):

**Give 775 permission to your `var` and `pub/media` directory.**

Run below command for the same.

- **sudo chmod -R 775 /var/generation**
- **sudo chmod -R 775 /pub/media**

If in case in your server **775** not work then try same command with **777** for those 2 folders and check.

Comment: Thanks @Manthan Dave. I ran your command and get below results.
`foysal@foysal-laptop /var/www/html/magento2 $ sudo chmod -R 775 /var/generation
chmod: cannot access '/var/generation': No such file or directory
foysal@foysal-laptop /var/www/html/magento2 $ sudo chmod -R 775 /pub/media
chmod: cannot access '/pub/media': No such file or directory
foysal@foysal-laptop /var/www/html/magento2 $ `

Answer (score 1):

changing permissions with `sudo` should be fine.

Anyway some info about permissions for Magento doc ;)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html
also
[Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

Give 775 permission to your var and pub/media directory.

Run below command for the same.

```
cd /path/to/your/project

sudo chmod -R 775 var/generation
sudo chmod -R 775 pub/media
```

check the user and group and correct it.