# custom email template issue magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, email-templates, xampp

I have got below error in email template.when i am adding header

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
```

**Error:**

> Error filtering template: Cannot read contents from file "D:/xampp/htdocs/magento217/" Warning!file_get_contents(D:/xampp/htdocs/magento217/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Can any one help me on this problem ? Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could have an issue with your Xampp configuration, check if all the folders and files have the correct permissions and the ownership for the magento installation.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

and checkout this related post:

[Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)