# Error 404 for rjsResolver.js in adminhtml and frontend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, 404-page

I have a big problem with this file.

What I need is to recreate this file:

> /pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/rjsResolver.js

What is problem: I have 404 when I enter backend or frontend for this one 
particular file.

What I do:

**Manually remove** `pub/static/frontend` and `pub/static/adminhtml`

**Run** `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` in the Magento root directory

**Run** `bin/magento cache:clean`

I think this one file is from https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/requirejs-config.js#L13

I check and didn't help: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2843
Checked: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6409

My problem is that I cannot enable "Sign Static Files" in server (some Nginx issues so no possible right now)

Is there a solution to recreate it?
It was work before update from 2.0;

I have now: Magento 2.1.7
I deploy static-files, have developer mode, cache clean, do some other stuff and nothing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So: there is list of issues to fight with.

---

Permission (most important: execute in pub/static)
[Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

---

In `core_config_data`

Be sure that in database use_rewrites are set to `0`

Check if there is path with "versionXXX" (frontend, or adminhtml) because you don't have entry `dev/static/sign` with `0`

1. Remove /di/*
2. Remove /generation/*
3. Generate di.xml by setup:di:compile
4. Deploy every theme in every language. (by using parameters)
5. Cache clean,cache flush
6. Remove manually pub/static/frontend/*
7. Clear Varnisch. It can hold files. There is possible to ban domain per user.