# Magento2 installation problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: magento2, installation

I am having following error when try to install Magento 2.1.7

> Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException:
>   The file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/var/.regenerate" cannot be
>   deleted Warning!unlink(/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/var/.regenerate):
>   Permission denied in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:382
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(172):
>   Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteFile('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
>    #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/GeneratedFiles.php(98):
>   Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->delete('/var/.regenerat...')
>    #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(114):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\GeneratedFiles->cleanGeneratedFiles() #3
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(385):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #4
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(362):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bo in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php
>   on line 382

Comment: Give 777 permission to pub and var folders

Comment: This is not permission issue, this means that you need to run this (with your data):

php magento setup:install \
   --admin-firstname=John \
   --admin-lastname=Smith \
   --admin-email=jsmith@mail.com \
   --admin-user=admin \
   --admin-password=password1 \
   --base-url=http://magento.local/ \
   --db-host=localhost \
   --db-name=magento \
   --db-user=magento \
   --db-password=magento \
   --currency=USD \
   --timezone=America/Chicago \
   --language=en_US \
   --use-rewrites=1

This error shows when you do not have created DB and connection with same.

Answer (score 0):

Set proper file and folder permissions of your Magento 2 project.

Follow [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)