# Magento Localhost var directory XAMPP

Tags: magento-1, localhost, xampp, directory

Facing the following error in my 'magento localhost'. Tried creating a 'tmp' folder in the 'root directory' but is not working. Maybe I'm creating it in the wrong directory? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chance that this is a permissions issue? Was going to leave a comment, but don't have high enough reputation. Magento's var directory is normally right inside the magento root, so where you created your temp folder should have been fine. Did you name it just 'var' or 'var_dir'?

Comment: Hello Codestr,
'var' folder was already created automatically. I just created 'var_dir' folder and 'tmp' folder as well. still not working. 
I created all folders in: '../XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/(magento)/
Is that correct?
Thanks

Comment: That would be the right location, I believe, but if the var directory already exists, I don't think adding another will help. Is that folder writeable by the webserver user? Aside from permissions I'm not sure what else would be the cause, I'm much more familiar with v2 than I am with v1.

Comment: How would I give permission to make the folder writable?

Comment: Use chmod and chown commands. To make sure the webserver can write to the location it will be something like `chown -R your-user:web-server /your/magento/root/*`, replacing the user names with your user and web server users respectively, and then the top answer here > https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions will tell you how to set file permissions