# Magento 2 File/Folder permissions

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

I am trying to install fresh Magento 2. It gives me `HTTP ERROR 500` when hit the URL `http://localhost/m2/`.

I know 0777 will solve my issue, but it is not good to give 777. I give permission as suggested. Please can any see below is there any file permission issue.

```
maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/m2$ ls -l
total 872
drwxr-xr-x  4 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy 435065 May 30 15:39 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy   1843 May 30 15:37 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy 344683 May 30 15:39 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy   3381 May 30 15:39 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy    631 May 30 15:39 COPYING.txt
drwxr-xr-x  5 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 dev
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy   2864 May 30 15:39 Gruntfile.js.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy   1368 May 30 15:39 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy    315 May 30 15:39 ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy  10376 May 30 15:39 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy  10364 May 30 15:39 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy   5071 May 30 15:39 nginx.conf.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy   1427 May 30 15:39 package.json.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 maddy maddy    814 May 30 15:39 php.ini.sample
drwxr-xr-x  2 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 phpserver
drwxr-xr-x  6 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 pub
drwxr-xr-x  7 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 setup
drwxr-xr-x  7 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:37 update
drwxr-xr-x  2 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 var
drwxr-xr-x 29 maddy maddy   4096 May 30 15:39 vendor
```

Comment: might be duplicate. Please refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Answer (score 3):

As per recommendations of Magento, the folder and file permission for Magento 2 installation should be like:

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;     # 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;     # 755 permission for directory 
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; # 777 permission for var folder    
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Note that if you access files using FTP, the FTP user should be a member of the webserver group.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command on root directory using terminal .

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

also clear the folder `var/cache` and then `reindexing`

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Sir I will try this , let you know. Thank YOu

Answer (score 0):

cd 
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;     # 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;     # 755 permission for directory
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ; # 777 permission for var folder
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chown -R : .
chmod u+x bin/magento

Then

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Then

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Then

sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ var/cache/ pub/static var