# How to add grunt watch to an app/code extension's css file in M2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, theme

I have been customizing the [landofcoder > Backend](https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-admin-theme.html) extension that creates an adminhtml theme.
It lives in the app/code/Ves/Backend folder.  However, the only thing I'd like to add is the ability to watch the .css file with grunt watch. Currently, it doesn't see any changes, and I have to continuously manually reload.

I've tried a simple themes.js config, but it could never find the CSS file because it's expecting it elsewhere for an admin theme.   If anybody has any pointers, suggestions on how to get the grunt to see the file, that would be amazing.
For full reference its:

```
app/code/Ves/backend/view/adminhtml/web/css/style.css
```

The Backend extension already has the following in its layout file, **app/code/Ves/backend/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/La‌​yout/etc/page_config‌​uration.xsd"> 
    <head> 
        <css src="Ves_Backend::css/styles.css" order="102"/> 
        <css src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-a‌​wesome.css" src_type="url"/> 
    </head> 
</page>
```

Yet the problem persists.

Comment: Hey, did you solve this after all? I'm wondering the same thing (although for frontend). Developing a custom extension in `app/code/` and don't want to reload all the time.

Answer (score 0):

**Install NodeJs in your pc**

**Use comand line:**

- Install Grunt CLI tool globally

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

* Install the node.js project dependency

```
npm install
```

* Remove Magento Cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

---

* Yor theme is `Magento/beckend` and `Ves/Backend` is an extension
* You must add in layout to call CSS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Ves_Backend::css/style.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

---

* Clean compiled files by command

```
grunt clean
```

* Run CMD command prompt with administrator privilege.

```
grunt exec:backend
grunt less:backend
grunt watch
```

https://drive.google.com/a/green-art.ro/file/d/0B_3mauXj4AQINXVoTXlBT2JSUjA/view?usp=sharing

---

**If that does not work grunt watch during development or run software from Php Storm roll back the following commands:**

* Remove Magento Cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

* Clean compiled files by command

```
grunt clean
```

* Run CMD command prompt with administrator privilege.

```
grunt exec:backend
grunt less:backend
grunt watch
```

Comment: The only question, when you say create a folder in the root project, do you mean the node_modules folder for grunt itself, or within the /app/code/Ves/backend folder ?

... or do you mean the root of the magento install itself?

Comment: "You must create a folder in root project `extend_gruntJs_theme`".
I specified that that folder should create it in the root of the project at the same level as the `app`. I did not specify anything by `node_modules`. `extend_gruntJs_theme` is the name of folder you must create.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought you meant, I just wanted to make sure my tired brain was processing that correctly. :) Cheers.

Comment: ok, so I got around to testing this, and I receive the error ">> [InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
>>   Verify entered values of the argument and options. Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Ves/backend/en_US/css/styles-m.less'"
The problem here is that the admin theme style file is actually in 
/app/code/Ves/Backend/view/adminhtml/web/css/styles.css

Comment: You need to add permissions  for `pub/static` - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Comment: I updated my answer. I think your the backend theme is `Magento/backend`

Comment: Do you mean I need to update the Magento/backend layout/default.xml or from Ves/backup ?  (The Ves/Backend/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml already has exactly what you typed).  I'm not sure how you have changed your answer, that makes it any different then a standard grunt execution.

Comment: this is a new code in my answare `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Ves_Backend::css/style.css"/>
    </head>
</page>`

Comment: Ok, thats what I was saying, the Backend extension already has that in the default.xml file: "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <head>
  <css src="Ves_Backend::css/styles.css" order="102"/>
  <css src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" src_type="url"/>
 </head>
</page>"

Yet the problem persists.

Comment: Why you have this `<css src="Ves_Backend::css/styles.css" order="102"/>` in current theme and not in extension ?

Comment: if you want to be helped, you have to ask the complete question, I now see that you have more stuff I do not know about.

Comment: I would like to say thanks for trying to help, I did however clarify this in my post a few days ago.  

To try and explain this in a different way. The extension (free from landofcoder.com) is an APP extension, that creates an adminhtml theme using a simply web/css web/images directory within the app/code/Ves/Backend extension itself. It does NOT create any files/folders in app/design.  So it seems that Grunt never SEE's the styles.css file within the extension itself.  Within that extension there is:

Comment: I can you help to remote.

Comment: app/code/Ves/Backend..
app/code/Ves/Backend/registration.php
app/code/Ves/Backend/composer.json
..etc/module.xml
..etc/adminhtml/system.xml
..etc/adminhtml/menu.xml
..view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml
..view/adminhtml/layout/web/css/styles.css
..view/adminhtml/layout/web/images/*.jpg

Comment: where you from?

Comment: @TheNorthern_Light well looks like this was a waste of everyone's time :) By chance were you able to figure this out? Obviously a css file that is part of a working extension is already going to be included in layout xml. The issue is that the grunt task for watch just doesn't know to also watch .css files, and the exec task doesn't create symlinks for .css files in an extension folder in app/code/{extension} or app/design/{extension}. There is something we need to modify in /dev/tools/