# Magento2: Redirecting to Cart page from Checkout page after Place Order

Tags: magento2, redirect

I added products to cart. Then did proceed to checkout. I have tried Cash on Delivery and Check / Money Order as Payment method. Everything is fine until the order review section. And then when I click the Place Order button then it gets redirected to Shopping Cart page instead of going to Order Success page. The cart items are still there.
How to solve it ?

Comment: This question has no effort in it. Please update with steps to reproduce , what you are using (clean install or not , which theme , custom theme?)  , screenshots...

Comment: I have debug it .actual result "Asymmetric transaction rollback."?How to resolve? @Sw At.Be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem :**"Asymmetric transaction rollback."**

Solution :

**1.** Clear your cache by manually deleting the content of `/var/cache/` folder , the `var/page-cache/` folder  and

> = Magento 2.2.0 -> `/generated/` folder
>   < Magento 2.2.0 -> `/var/generation/*` folder

**2.** reindex your website by using the SSH command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

**3.** Make sure your website is in `developer mode` or in `production mode` and not in `default mode'. You can check it by using the command`php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`. If it is in`default mode`you can change it to`production or developer mode`by using the command`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`or`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`.

Before you use these commands clear your var/view_preprocessed folder and your pub/static folder also (afterwhich you need to recompile your pub/static folder with the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Also be sure all your permissions of the folders are set like how Magento wants it more information on that here = [Permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)