# Magento 2 place order redirecting to the cart page

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3

When I am trying to **"Place Order"** -> it is redirecting to cart page,
the order is not placed and cart items are in the cart.

I tried this solution, but unsuccessfully.

I use **Mageplaza_Osc**

> .../checkout/onepage/success -> Status Code: 302 Found

**Do you have some ideas?**

Comment: I see in the documentation that Mageplaza_Osc is compatible with 2.3.x, but have you tried disabling that module and testing?

Comment: which payment method you are using? try with COD as check its working or not.

Comment: Go to Stores - > Sales - > Checkout - > Shopping Cart There is Option : - After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart Set to No

Comment: The question is about the redirection to cart after the order has been placed not after adding a product to cart

Comment: which solution did you try?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151328)

Comment: @magefms this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/199283/64128

Comment: Are you on 2.3.1 by any chance? This started happening for me with 2.3.1 on all one step checkout solutions I've tried

Comment: @gabtzi i am on 2.3.1 & got exactly the same problem. Even if i use the banktransfer payment method, it redirects to the cart with the products still in it. Would be nice if some could solve that.

Comment: I'm happy I'm not alone with that. It seems that in 2.3.1 there are a lot of changes in how checkout session is handled that's why this bug occured. Unfortunately it's not something the Magento team would handle since it's the extensions that fail and not magento itself. While stepping through the code for each of the modules after the placeOrder function I see that the flow is correct but at the end when it's redirecting to success page the checkout session is empty. It's also happening in all offline payment methods for me too and started after the upgrade.

Comment: @dukir, Have you found any solution for this issue? We are facing the same. Please let us know if you find any.

Comment: u can try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251106/magento2-checkout-onepage-success-redirects-to-cart

Comment: If you are using mageplaza extension's then you should try to contact support team for it. Because this is paid extension so they are responsible to give solution for it

Comment: Do you find any solution? I have Mageplaza OSC too, i face this issue only in registered users. I try to disable OSC and the issue is still persist. I use Magento 2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Magento makes redirect to cart when something is wrong during making order process. 302 code say that there was redirect.

You should check logs and there should be an answer. Something goes wrong during making order and that's why you were moved to cart.