# Readiness Check Failure in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, extensions, magento-2.2.5, readiness-check

I am getting the below error on updating a marketplace extension in backend (`System->Websetup Wizard->Extension Manager`).

> Check Cron Scripts Cron script readiness check failed. Hide detail
>
> Error from Setup Application Cron Script: Cron job has not been
>   configured yet Other checks will fail as a result (**PHP version**, **PHP
>   settings**, and **PHP extensions**)
>
> Error from Updater Application Cron Script: Cron job has not been
>   configured yet
>
> For additional assistance, see cron scripts help.
>
> Check Component Dependency We found conflicting component
>   dependencies. Hide detail
>
> Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>   - Installation request for dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension 3.2.0 -> satisfiable by dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension[3.2.0].
>   - dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension 3.2.0 requires magento/framework >=100 <103 -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>   - A typo in the package name
>   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>   details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.
>
> For additional assistance, see component dependency help .
>
> PHP Settings Check * For additional assistance, see PHP settings check
>   help .
>
> Need Help?
>
> PHP Extension Help PHP Extensions Check missing PHP extensions. Hide
>   detail
>
> The best way to resolve this is to install the correct missing
>   extensions. The exact fix depends on our server, your host, and other
>   system variables.  Our PHP extension help can get you started.
>
> For additional assistance, contact your hosting provider.

How to Fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Run the below commands from your Magento_root to run the cron manually & then start again with your extension installation.

```
Php bin/magento cron:run
php update/cron.php
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Run the readiness check again it will work!

Comment: Cron is working and readiness check still shows failure..

Comment: What error it is showing now?

Comment: Same error a i mentioned in the question above.

Comment: try to run `composer update` command

Comment: No.. after running composer update i am getting error as "Could not open input file: /var/www/html/magento225/bin/magento"...and my setup is not working at all :(

Comment: There is file permission issue please try to give the file permission [try tihs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209680/file-permissions-magento-2)

Answer (score 2):

> The readiness check makes sure your server and environment are set up
>   correctly for enabling or disabling modules.

**Readiness check failure Causes**

- [Updater check failure](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/updater.html)
- [Cron script check failure](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html)
- [Component dependency check failure](http://Component%20dependency%20check%20failure)
- [PHP version readiness check issues](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/php-version.html)
- [PHP settings errors](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_php-set.html)
- [PHP extensions check failure](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements.html)

**Readiness check success Example**

[image]

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/module-man/compman-readiness.html

**I hope this will help**