# Magento 2 : 500 Error internal server

Tags: magento-2.0, http-error-500

I  upload the data local to server . I changed `env.php` file and also change `core_config_data` table but when I run url on server it gives me `500` server error. while on `local` its run perfectly. can any one help me?

Error Like Below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Can't create directory /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/. in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Framewo...') #3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Framewo...') #4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Framewo...') #5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runt in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 103
```

I am using magento version: `2.0.2`

Comment: enable error reporting it will show you the error

Comment: how to enable error reporting? I am newbie to magento 2

Comment: you can enable display_errors from app/bootstrap.php file. At line no. 11 remove # from the start `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: @piyush , thanks , I edit my question please give me response

Comment: please run commands given in below answer by @SureshChikani

Comment: I already used that command but not helped me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below command and check

```
rm -rf var/page_cache var/cache var/composer_home var/generation var/di var/view_preprocessed
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento indexer:clean
php bin/magento cache:c
```

Give full permissions to var folder : [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I edit the question so please give me answer..

Comment: Check my updated answer, give permission to var/ folder.

Comment: how to give permission and which permission?

Comment: I give all the permission but still the same error comes . I think am missing something , so can you please give me step by step answer

Comment: Check which URL run in console or also you can check it with enable developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

Give correct permissions to your directories.

Recommended settings for the permissions are as follows:

```
All directories have 770 permissions.

770 permissions give full control (that is, read/write/execute) to the owner and to the group and no permissions to anyone else.

All files have 660 permissions.

660 permissions mean the owner and the group can read and write but other users have no permissions.
```

Try to run these commands in SSH and your permissions should be sorted:

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

You can find out more information on this website: https://devdocs.magento.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
```