# SOLVED: Magento 2 GET 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: magento2, apache, http-error-500, xampp

[image]I have apache mode enabled, permissions given but im still getting the GET 500 Server error:

SOLUTION AT: [Magento CSS Not Loading Error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229060/magento-css-not-loading-error/229066?noredirect=1#comment318972_229066)

Comment: Your pub directory has not write permission for pub directory provide it 777 permission.

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess file ?

Comment: No i havent, how do i  that?

Comment: check `.htaccess` file exist in `pub/` and `pub/static/` folders.

Comment: there is that file under pub/static

Comment: try this  now delete cache folder and delete `frontend` and `adminhtml` from `pub/static/` folder then re run `php bin/magento setup:static:deploy nl_NL -f`

Comment: dude thank you so much comment on this post ill give you +

Comment: check my answer, it might be help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Run the Following Command in the command line.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: i have 3 files as debug.log, exception.log, system.log but none of them are usefull i looked into them all

Comment: see @suresh Chikani's answer..

Comment: and also follow this link:`https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211342/magento-2-500-error-internal-server`

Comment: @Compu Scie , if your problem solved then pls upvote the answer for the others use

Answer (score 0):

There is a language issue with deploy content, you can run below command for multiple locale

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static:deploy nl_NL en_US -f
```