# 500 internal server error- Magento 2

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

i am having an error on my website.
following is the image :
[image]

i've been trying to fix the error but can't find what excatly sould i do?
can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Please check your log files to get the exact reason behind the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple,you *have permission issue on server*.You ***don't set proper setting at files or folders***.

You have **set permission like 755** which is ***wrong as per as your server***.Please ask to ***hosting provider  which is permission proper for files/folders***.

Please follow blog like:

[Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html