# Can't change home page

Tags: magento2, frontend, design, home-page

**Issue:-**

I have recently taken over a Magento site.  The client would like their home page to be changed to their About Us page.  When I go to the

`GENERAL->web->Default Pages and change the CMS Home Page to About Us.`

I saved the config for both the default and the Main Web Site but it does not want to change.  I have been searching for days trying to figure this out.  Am I missing something?  Is there something else I can try?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Please clear your browser cache and Magento cache from backend

Comment: If clearing the cache doesn't work, change the scope in the top-left corner of your configuration page, and see if there are any different settings than the ones that you set.  If so, these would override your changes.

Comment: It shows the Default Config, Main Site, which I have changed to "About Us".  There is one other item in the drop down but I am not able to select it.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: flushed the cache on both admin panel and in browser still not changing.

Comment: Also, search though any files within your entire project with the name cms_index_index.xml. The page might be set in one of them.

Comment: also you may (for sanity check) want to actually delete the cache files on the server even if you flush Magento Cache through the admin.  <magento_root_folder>/var/cache/mage--*    files.

Comment: Run cache clean and flush, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your homepage doesn't change from the admin config, please check all this:

1. Set the right `storeview` scope in top left corner, then change the homepage
2. Clean the `Magento` and `Browser` cache.
3. Check the `xml` files if this home page has not been set with an xml config:

   `app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{themeName}/layout/local.xml` and find if you have this layout handle `cms_index_index` then the home page will be set as something like this:

   ```
   <cms_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>...</template></action> //Or <action method="setBlockId">
       </reference>
   </cms_index_index>
   ```

   Look also if you have some `cms_index_index.xml` file in your current theme.
4. Try to enable the path hints to check if this homepage is loaded from an phtml or from cms block

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen.  This is definitely a permissions issue on your server files.
Fix your permissions from here: [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

Then I usually force a deploy to make sure all the permissions "stick":

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```