# Unable to install Modules Magento 2.2 ( Readiness Check Error)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

Im trying to install a few modules for the better functionality of my store.

I've previously installed modules and themes and have basic knowledge about using SSh, etc.

However I'm facing a few problems while installing different Modules(Extensions from Magento Marketplace and also Github).

When i install this module from SSH Host using module:enable command.

***Update:***

Thats how my admin panel looks

[image: Thats how my admin panel looks]

That is how my site looks
[image]

Comment: this is a common problem which occur every time we install module via admin.
Try installing the module by extracting there files via ftp and hit setup:upgrade

Comment: as i wrote above, When i try to install using this method, some things my admin panel as well and frontend crash

Comment: what you face over frontend?

Comment: Some error when checking out. maybe because my module is checkout based

Answer (score 0):

Check bleow link : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html
Issue with your corn job set up

Comment: I tried this but got error from SSH Client "Permission Denied"

Comment: and also im not able to setup up my permissions and all

Comment: cd <your Magento install dir> 

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento   You need run this command for permission on files and folder

Comment: do you have Permission denied for public key ? 
its good to share screen shot of the error for better understand the problem

Comment: hi. while trying to get my permissions, i dont know what happened. my site (carefone.in) crashed now(like html is diplayed but not the css) and my backend is also not working properly. also my backup is not restoring. What should i do?

Comment: did you perform command correctly ? please do static content deploy once and flush the cache  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
for caching  : php bin/magento cache:flush
Let me know after that if still not solve the issue

Comment: i dont know. i was following magento docs and commands like chmod chown etc. i dont know when my site and backend crashed. Earlier my mode was default, somehow it changed to production and now it cant be changed beacuse i dont have permission to env.php (something like that)

Comment: after performing static content deploy. im getting this error -- Deploy using quick strategy


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
  The path "deployed_version.txt:///home/carefdgi/public_html/pub/static/" is
   not writable

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa follow this soluction you might be a don't have proper owner ship and permission either you have to contact with your hosting provider to setup proper  permission and ownership for magento

Comment: thsese things are too complicated. i will have to get a way to get my backup back on as im failing to restore it through cpanel

Comment: im getting some or the other kind of error

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: i didnt save it and my putty shut down. but could tell it wasnt working

Comment: do you still facing error ?

Comment: no i fixed it from another solution - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229963/magento-2-backend-and-frontend-crashed/229975?noredirect=1#comment320448_229975

Answer (score 0):

Thats how my admin panel looks

[image: Thats how my admin panel looks]

That is how my site looks
[image]

Comment: run this command in terminal php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Getting error -  Deploy using quick strategy


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
  The path "deployed_version.txt:///home/carefdgi/public_html/pub/static/" is
   not writable

Comment: okay run chmod -R 777 pub/static and again run above commnad

Comment: Deploy using quick strategy


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
  Directory "/home/carefdgi/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static" can
  not be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied


now this

Comment: and FYI, i was able to run these commands (static-content:deploy) before today as ive installed the themes and modules in my site. I dont understand the cause of this problem

Comment: please run chmod -R 777 pub/ 
after that again deploy content

Comment: carefdgi@md-in-63 [~]# cd public_html
carefdgi@md-in-63 [~/public_html]# chmod -R 777 pub/
carefdgi@md-in-63 [~/public_html]# php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Deploy using quick strategy


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
  Directory "/home/carefdgi/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static" can
  not be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied