# Magento 2 backend and frontend crashed

Tags: magento2

It all started when i was not able to install modules on my site due to cron job not running. But due to permission errors and all, and after following some steps shown in devdocs magento. My site and backend crashed. I suspect it is due to changing deploy mode to production. Now im not able to change my mode( not permitted) and my back and frontend look like this

[image]

[image]

[Unable to install Modules Magento 2.2 ( Readiness Check Error)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229799/unable-to-install-modules-magento-2-2-readiness-check-error)

my follow up post

Comment: This will be happen when css and js are not calling properly. Please check once the js and css structure

Comment: Regenerate your CSS and JS - this should get your site looking like it did beforehand. Run the `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

Comment: [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
  Directory "/home/carefdgi/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static" can
  not be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied
-- getting this error

Comment: @Tanish Make sure you follow the instructions in the Dev Docs and run those (or indeed any bin/magento) commands as the web server user, otherwise you will run into these permissions errors: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html#install-update-depend-user-switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try following commands it may help you; Run all the commands. I have faced this issue frequently.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: oh. it worked. Thanks a lot @rk1990. Been spending almost 2 hours on stupid commands and the fix was the easiest

Comment: then please vote for the ans :) ... it will help to rank the ans and may be useful for others ... cheers

Comment: oh i already did but isnt publically shown due to my reputation score

Answer (score 0):

```
 - bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer 
 - sudo chmod -R 777 .
 - sudo rm -rf pub/* 
 - sudo rm -rf generation/ 
 - sudo rm -rf var/cache/ 
 - bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
 - bin/magento s:d:c
```

Comment: getting error -   Deployment config file env.php is not writable.

Comment: It's best to actually explain what these commands do when answering a question, otherwise this answer is not very useful to other people

Comment: @Tanish `sudo chmod -R 777 .`  from root project

Comment: @Evgeniy how to do it from root project??

Comment: @Tanish root project - this folder project

Comment: carefdgi@md-in-63 [~]# cd public_html
carefdgi@md-in-63 [~/public_html]# sudo chmod -R 777
-bash: sudo: command not found
carefdgi@md-in-63 [~/public_html]#

Comment: @Tanish I don't see point in end

Comment: @Tanish `sudo chmod -R 777 .`

Comment: getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

you can try following commands it may help you

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clear