# Unable to create/visualize products

Tags: magento2.2

I recently installed a third party theme and I'm unable to previsualize any product, I got the following error when accessing through url:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/pub/media/catalog" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/pub/media/catalog" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied
#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(218): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('/opt/bitnami/ap...', 511)
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(199): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('/opt/bitnami/ap...', 511)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(89): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->createDirectory('/opt/bitnami/ap...', 511)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image/Context.php(48): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->create('catalog/product')
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\Image\Context->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem))
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...')
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Catalog...')
#8 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'context', 'Magento\\Catalog...')
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
#12 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/View/Asset/ImageFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Catalo...', Array)
#13 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php(406): Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\ImageFactory->create(Array)
#14 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(500): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image->setBaseFile(NULL)
#15 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(470): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->initBaseFile()
#16 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(551): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->applyScheduledActions()
#17 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageBuilder.php(133): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->getResizedImageInfo()
#18 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php(516): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder->create()
#19 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct->getImage(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'product_base_im...', Array)
#20 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->___callParent('getImage', Array)
#21 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'product_base_im...')
#22 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(455): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getImage', Array, Array)
#23 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/design/frontend/Meigee/barbour/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml(14): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->getImage(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'product_base_im...')
#24 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/opt/bitnami/ap...')
#25 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor), '/opt/bitnami/ap...', Array)
#26 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/opt/bitnami/ap...')
#27 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->fetchView('/opt/bitnami/ap...')
#28 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#29 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(869): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#30 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->toHtml()
#31 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('opengraph.gener...')
#32 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('opengraph.gener...')
#33 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('opengraph.gener...')
#34 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('opengraph.gener...', true)
#35 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(511): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('opengraph.gener...', true)
#36 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/design/frontend/Meigee/barbour/Magento_Theme/templates/html/container.phtml(10): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml()
#37 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/opt/bitnami/ap...')
#38 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template), '/opt/bitnami/ap...', Array)
#39 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/opt/bitnami/ap...')
#40 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#41 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(250): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#42 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#43 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#44 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#45 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#46 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#47 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#48 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#49 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#50 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#51 {main}
```

Comment: is anyone related to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you have in your post mentions "permissions denied". Might be a good idea to verify the media folder permissions particularly.

you might want to take a look at the following link: [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)