# Css and Js files are not loading in admin panel and storefront

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3, localhost, windows

I have setup **Magento 2.2.3 enterprise edition** store in my local windows system.

Previously, the CSS and JS were loading and the store was appearing fine.

[image: Store's Admin Panel Screenshot]

[image: StoreFront Screenshot]

But recently the CSS and JS files are not loading (shows 404 error when checked in chrome DevTools network).

[image: Chrome DevTools Screenshot]

I have tried giving commands like cache:clean, cache:flush, indexer:reindex, setup:di:compile and also setup:static-content:deploy but the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Follow below steps:

1. Make new static folder under pub folder and copy .htaccess file from old pub/static folder to new static folder.
2. Run query in database : INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
3. Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (add -f argument for magento 2.2.x)
4. Run php bin/magento cache:flush

Now, test it and the css should load.

Comment: its working fine :)

Comment: I'm join to this community right now just to voteup you. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Run Commands from your Magento root directory

> - php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check once permission of the folder and files .
for that follow below link : 
[Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions).

Also check is there ht-access file in pub folder after that run command:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: if after this still not found the soluction you can follow this step:

Remove pub/static [Keep the .htaccess backed up and copy it again]

Remove var/cache

Remove var/composer_home

Remove var/generation

Remove var/page_cache

Remove var/view_preprocessed

run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Go to your htaccess file and find the

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment this line and then try again

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Do this in pub directory htaccess, media, and also on root .
Still if css and js  are not loading then let me know I will provide you one more solution for this

Comment: Didn't work. Should I give any commands after commenting?

Comment: See, what happens when we have magento installed..
static files are generated in pub folder. So firstly we have to check there permissions that files are permitted to get generated or not?
then if we are in developer mode and we don't need to manually deploy the static files i.e the answers provided by others..
and now your case try to check whether you have files in pub/ static directory or not and then check by direct hitting any css/ js URL..
and check if htaccess is available there or not and it is commented as per my comment

Answer (score 0):

When U Install Magento That time Not Add The Js file in pub folder if u Run below command than all Js and templates file deploy in pub Folder

now run this command step by step

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If not working than after u can also run with your store
But if you know which store and with language store you create
For example

php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. You need to give full permission to your project directory.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 directoryname
```

Hope this will work :)