# Operation not permitted

Tags: magento2.2, file-permissions, linux

I am trying to install a Magento 2 in Linux Mint 19. I am facing issue in file permission.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

Comment: Thanks @MagenX for your reply. I followed that question. I executed commands. But I cant see output in Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with permission with **var** and **generation** folder.

Use the below command

```
chmod -R 777 var generated
```

Then run your `setup:upgrade` command.

Comment: You solution is not working. I am getting same error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKJMr.png

Comment: Seems the permission issue is with whole magento 2 code base. Please give the permission to the project root folder, replace 777 with your exact permission as per your server settings.

Comment: Thanks @Sourabh, What should I do ?

Comment: Please use this command: chmod -R 644 .

Comment: This solution is not giving error. But I am getting error `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /magento2/ on this server.` in browser while trying to browse magento2 folder.

Comment: You will have to execute the above command with sudo that is super user permission as: sudo chmod -R 644 .

Comment: I used like this `foysal@foysal:/var/www/html$ sudo chmod -R 644 /var/www/html/magento2/`

Comment: No go to your project folder and then execute the above command.

Comment: Your problem is with  the missing permissions.