# Install Magento 2 in Linux Mint

Tags: magento2.2, linux

I installed `WordPress` in my Linux Mint successfully. I used `sudo chmod 777 -R  /var/www/html/wordpress/corewordpress`

[image]

I am trying to install `Magento2` same way but I can't.

[image]

Why it is happening ?

Comment: are you trying to install into local machine? might be happened due to permission issue try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95033/55928 you can check server log if there is any error

Comment: can you enable error reporting by app/bootstrap.php  file uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); then check what is error here ?

Comment: Thank you @Hit's. Yes, I am trying to install into local machine. WordPress is installed perfectly. Why magento is creating issue ? Thanks.

Comment: @Hit's, I followed your link previously. But did not get any result.

Comment: do you face any error in the server log? why don't you try by localhost/ma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code on the top of your index.php(of Magento) file then you will get the exact error:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thanks @Saphal Jha. I am getting below erro

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfrM2.png

Comment: That means you are using magento2 in php 7.2 @abuabu . and magento 2 not supporting in php 7.2 yet

Comment: Thanks @AnsarHusain. Which PHP version should I use ?

Comment: use 7.0 yet if  you are using magento2.2.X @abuabu

Comment: @abuabu Switch your PHP version to 7.1 and try again