# Notice: getimagesize(): Read error

Tags: magento2.2.3

I am getting error like this

```
{"0":"Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/Product\/Image.php on line 890","1":"#0 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'getimagesize():...', '\/home\/rahul\/p...', 890, Array)\n#1 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/Product\/Image.php(890): getimagesize('\/home\/rahul\/p...')\n#2 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Helper\/Image.php(552): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Image->getResizedImageInfo()\n#3 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ImageBuilder.php(132): Magento\\Catalog\\Helper\\Image->getResizedImageInfo()\n#4 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/AbstractProduct.php(516): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ImageBuilder->create()\n#5 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\AbstractProduct->getImage(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), 'related_product...', Array)\n#6 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Related\\Interceptor->___callParent('getImage', Array)\n#7 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Related\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), 'related_product...')\n#8 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Block\/Product\/ProductList\/Related\/Interceptor.php(351): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Related\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getImage', Array, Array)\n#9 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/var\/view_preprocessed\/pub\/static\/app\/design\/frontend\/Sm\/bestshop\/Magento_Catalog\/templates\/product\/list\/related.phtml(1): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Related\\Interceptor->getImage(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), 'related_product...')\n#10 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/TemplateEngine\/Php.php(59): include('\/home\/rahul\/p...')\n#11 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/Template.php(270): Magento\\Framework\\View\\TemplateEngine\\Php->render(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Related\\Interceptor), '\/home\/rahul\/p...', Array)\n#12 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Block\/Product\/ProductList\/Related\/Interceptor.php(440): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template->fetchView('\/home\/rahul\/p...')\n#13 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/Template.php(300): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Related\\Interceptor->fetchView('\/home\/rahul\/p...')\n#14 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template->_toHtml()\n#15 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Block\/Product\/ProductList\/Related\/Interceptor.php(765): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\AbstractBlock->toHtml()\n#16 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/app\/code\/LR\/Catalog\/Controller\/Index\/Custom.php(44): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Related\\Interceptor->toHtml()\n#17 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/generated\/code\/LR\/Catalog\/Controller\/Index\/Custom\/Interceptor.php(24): LR\\Catalog\\Controller\\Index\\Custom->execute()\n#18 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php(107): LR\\Catalog\\Controller\\Index\\Custom\\Interceptor->execute()\n#19 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#20 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): LR\\Catalog\\Controller\\Index\\Custom\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#21 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): LR\\Catalog\\Controller\\Index\\Custom\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#22 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/generated\/code\/LR\/Catalog\/Controller\/Index\/Custom\/Interceptor.php(39): LR\\Catalog\\Controller\\Index\\Custom\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#23 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): LR\\Catalog\\Controller\\Index\\Custom\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#24 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#25 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#26 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#27 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#28 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#29 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#30 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#31 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#32 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#33 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#34 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#35 \/home\/rahul\/public_html\/index.php(62): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#36 {main}","url":"\/custom\/index\/custom","script_name":"\/index.php"}rahul@rahulphoto.com
```

Comment: Please check file and folder permissions. This is most likely trying to load a file it's not permitted to. Focus on `pub/media` folder.
You can refer to this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95033/44585

Comment: Thanks @Zankar actually other images are loading properly, for only one category images I am getting this error . So I guess directory permissions are fine , what you suggest ?

Comment: try figruing out the file causing the error (the category image) and check out that file. It might be corrupted in some way.

Comment: thanks @Zankar , I will try this and let you know if it works for me or not . thanks

Comment: @Zankar thanks for the tip , it worked for me . can you please post it as a answer so that  I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very likely due to insufficient permissions on a specific file/folder. You should check file and folder permissions, especially for the `pub/media` folder. You can refer to this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95033/44585
You should also try to find the specific file causing the problem so you can investigate the issue quicker.

To fix the file and directory permissions run these commands:

```
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cross check your associated product images, some images must me corrupted or with size 0 bytes. Just go to your directory "/media/catalog/product/" and check images with 0 size.

Comment: in my case - this was the cause. removing the file with a zero size resolved the issue.
thank you)