# Magento 2.2.6 not open after unzip and include all the extensions

Tags: installation, magento2.2.6

I am new to the magento development. I am trying to install magento 2.2.6 .
My configurations

```
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
PHP Version 7.0.32
Ubuntu 16.04
mysql 5.7.24
```

I have downloaded magento 2.2.6 (full release with sample data) from `https://magento.com/tech-resources/download` . then try to open `localhost/magento`.

It says

```
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

while i try `composer install` command

it provides output

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

What is the problem why i cant open magento setup in my locahost

[image]

**ANSWER**

I have found what is wrong .. `I check the error log file and found out var folder permission issue`. After i provide permission it working properly

Comment: I have found what is wrong .. I check the error log file and found out var folder permission issue. After i provide permission it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide chmod 777 permissions to the var, pub, generates and etc while before installing in magento 2, After that permissions you can start the magento setup. Remove the permission of files under etc folder to 644 after installation as this may cause security issues because files under etc folder contains sensitive information about our database.

cd < your Magento install dir >

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;   #644 permission for files   
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;   #755 permission for directory 
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; #777 permission for var folder    
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

More you can see at

[Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

Mark this answer as tick if you got it.