# how do I set folder permissions on windows Magento 2.2 install?

Tags: magento2.2, file-permissions, windows

I'm using laragon in a windows 10 machine for a 2.2.3 Magento install. What folder permissions do I have to set?

By default, all folders are read-only (or so it seems). Currently, I set writable folders (and files):
/var/
/pub/media
/pub/static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below link it will help you out
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 0):

You can give write permission by running below command in your CLI.

```
takeown /F <folder name>
```

For Example:

```
 takeown /F C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\pub\static
```

Comment: How to give write permission to vendor folder in windows 7?  Is your takeown /F command  okay? what about attrib?

Answer (score 0):

I hope so below link is use full for you.

> [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)