# How to solve newly generated magento 2 file permission issue in ubantu 18.04?

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

I have install and configured magento 2 in ubantu 18.04. Everything work fine but when i am run magento2 command using cli than every time it will display file permission issue in **"cache_dir"** and **"generated"** folder.

I am try to give permission using this link [Permission solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

But no luck.

Comment: you local user and the webserver user should be in a group together. and the magento folder should be owned by that group

Answer (score 0):

**umask** feature is specially made of new files permission.

default umask in magento2 is 002
If you want to change it then just create a file name **magento_umask** and put your value in it.

For more information you can check
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html

Comment: I am create one file "magento_umask" and put value 002 and store in root and after that i am deploy my project and same issue arrive.

Comment: make sure you have setuped magento user in correct way also the files ownership and group permissions are correct.
and never run magento commands through sudo or root user.

Comment: I have run command 2 times using sudo(root), So if i am remove this magento 2 setup folder and make new one and install new setup and run command without sudo than it will resolve this issue ?

Comment: create one user for magento and run commands through magento user.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html