# Magento2 Installation Error by 0%

Tags: magento2, error, installation, docker

since a few days I am trying to install Magento with Docker, Composer on Windows 10.

So far, I got to the Web-Installation. A huge step for me...

After clicking the last step, Magento stuck by 0%.

The Logfiles shows something like:

> [2019-02-14 12:16:38] main.CRITICAL: The path
>   "/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php.86"
>   cannot be renamed into
>   "/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php"
>   Warning!rename(/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php.86,/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php):
>   No such file or directory Class
>   Magento\Paypal\Model\PayflowlinkFactory generation error: The
>   requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated'
>   directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the
>   'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated'
>   directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not
>   generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
>   signature of the related construct method, only. [] [] [2019-02-14
>   12:16:39] main.CRITICAL: The path
>   "/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php.78"
>   cannot be renamed into
>   "/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php"
>   Warning!rename(/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php.78,/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php):
>   No such file or directory Class
>   Magento\Paypal\Model\PayflowlinkFactory generation error: The
>   requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated'
>   directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the
>   'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated'
>   directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not
>   generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
>   signature of the related construct method, only. [] [] [2019-02-14
>   12:16:48] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"POST","url":"http://m2.docker/setup/index.php/session/prolong","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}}
>   [] [2019-02-14 12:16:53] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"POST","url":"http://m2.docker/setup/index.php/session/prolong","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}}
>   []"

If I should guess, its something wrong with docker but I can't figure out how to solve this. I found ONE question similar to this. It was asked in Januar and no one answered it till today.. No clue whats wrong.

Thank for you help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct your permissions .
Do a :

```
rm -rf generated/* 
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

Than

```
find app/code var/view_preprocessed vendor pub/static app/etc generated/code generated/metadata \( -type f -or -type d \) -exec chmod u-w {} + && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

or follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions) for more detail.

Comment: Sorry, it is not solved!

What do I do if I am on Windows10, running this on Docker? 
Windows has no chmod. Any Idea maybe??

Comment: Okay, I got it.. 
For any Windows10, Docker Beginner:

In ur .yaml File u link the volume of ur PC Folder with ur stored data.
This is accessable over the apache container like this: docker exec -it --user root apache2_service bin/bash.

In your bash you can cd to the counterpart of your linked volume in the yaml. 
Here you can do ALL the magic (chmod the folrders and files).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I solved this issue with restarting Apache! 
That does the trick for me.

I don`t know if I will stumble again over your answer because Im still facing problems and it may come to the point I will need it.

Bye