# why checkout and cart page not showing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shopping-cart, ubuntu

my site **not showing checkout and cart page**

why this happening ??

**Checkout page**
[image: Checkout page]

**Cart page**
[image: Cart page]

can anyone find the solution

Comment: Please check once time system.log or exception.log

Comment: do u know linux

Comment: Yes. I know that

Comment: i have problem when i run cli comments the file and folder permission changes every time 
how i can solve

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Comment: Still if you have problem please contact me easyndfaster@gmail.com.

Comment: Thank you after l will try any error found i will text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90939/discussion-between-sweety-masmiya-and-prabhakaran7).