# Can't access admin after update Magento 2.3.1

Tags: admin, upgrade, admin-controller, magento2.3.1

I recently updated my Magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.1, and my site works, but I when I try to go to my admin url I get a 504 error. I have tried clearing my cache, and I tried following advice to clear the values of the cookie paths in my database:

[image: screenshot of database]

The last error I have in my error log is :AH01630: client denied by server configuration. My config.php looks right, but I'm not sure.

```
'Magento_Cookie' => 1,
```

I didn't get any errors when I updated. It still doesn't work. What should my next steps be?

EDIT:
After being able to log in I was having a hard time getting to pages, because all the caches were disabled, so make sure to enable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error in earlier version. Finally it was permissions issue. Check the permissions of [file system](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html) may be this is the reason

Comment: Do you know what you changed to make it work? The dev doc you linked just talks about what user to use, and I have an non-root user that i do my updates in. thanks

Comment: I just ran cmod and chown for the entire installation and something was fixed.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean? could you post the commands you ran?

Comment: for example see the first answer here :https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: okay thanks let me try that!

Comment: Okay, so I did the lower one because I didn't want to do the 777 open permissions for everything, but now i can log in!