# Something went wrong while saving the file(s)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, category-image

After Saving the category from the admin side, it successfully saved the category. But in the `exception.log` file I got the following error.

```
"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Something went wrong while saving the file(s). at /opt/lampp/htdocs/m2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ImageUploader.php:215)"
```

Any Help will be appreciated. My Magento version is 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like permissions issue, try to fix it for the whole project:

- [Magento 2 DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)
- [StacExchange answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

anyway I'll recommend you to check all images which saving during category save process using the xDebug or something similar, because exception throws when magento trying to copy/move a media file from one place to another.

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: Thanks, can you please answer my below que: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275245/after-migration-layer-navigation-not-showing-magento-1-9-to-magento-2-3-1