# Magento 2 installation in GoDaddy shared hosting

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions, hosting, godaddy

Just installed Magento in my GoDaddy shared hosting and getting this error:

> Can't create directory
>   /home/xxx/public_html/xxx.com/ecommerce/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Index/.
>   Class Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Index\Interceptor
>   generation error: The requested class did not generate properly,
>   because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.

If --- after running the `bin/magento setup:di:compile` CLI command when the `generated` directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

The permissions for all dirs were changed to 777.

Comment: Does the generated folder exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)