# Fatal error... Can sombody help me

Tags: fatal-error

```
      if ($generator !== null) {
            $this->tryToLoadSourceClass($className, $generator);
            if (!($file = $generator->generate())) {
                $errors = $generator->getErrors();
                throw new \RuntimeException(implode(' ', $errors) . ' in [' . $className . ']');
            }
            if (!$this->definedClasses->isClassLoadableFromMemory($className)) {
                $this->_ioObject->includeFile($file);
            }
            return self::GENERATION_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: throw new \RuntimeException(implode(' ', $errors) . ' in [' . $className . ']');

Comment: they  said that that one is the error, how should i change

Comment: Check generated folder on root directory and give 777 permission to that folder. Did you get any class name on error log?

Comment: is not working..

Comment: Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create directory /var/www/vhosts/nedeias.ro/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/. in [Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy] in /var/www/vhosts/nedeias.ro/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115

Comment: Which Magento version you are using? Any error

Comment: 2.2.3           I want to add a plugin, adn after that... the website was fall

Comment: Two possibilities, 1. Plugin code having some issues 2. If without using custom plugin if you still face error and then fix folder permissions part.

Comment: i wrote this php bin/magento setup:upgrade, after that i wrote this       php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy                they give e this, after i put this code line

Comment: [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException] NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes. In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand. If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: 'bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f' they give me that, and i wrote with deploy -f...

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/91870/34579

Comment: i don t undestand...

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Everyone always assumes it is folder and files permissions error but it could also be an owner and group owner issue.  FTP in and have a look at the file/folder permissions but also at the owner and group owner permissions.  I can give you the commends to change all of the file/folder/owner/group owner if required

Comment: i fix that.... but i need now to fix the plugin....Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mageplaza\CallForPrice\Helper\Data::isEnabled() in /var/www/vhosts/nedeias.ro/public_html/app/code/Mageplaza/CallForPrice/Observer/CallForPriceLayoutLoadBefore.php:67

Answer (score 0):

**To set permissions and ownership for directories.**

**Execute below command on the CLI**

```
 cd /var/www/vhosts/nedeias.ro/public_html/ && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

For more ref this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

**NOTE**: In case Magento root is different then path change is required.(`/var/www/vhosts/nedias.ro/public_html/`)

Comment: The above sets files to 664 and directories to 775.....................

Comment: i fix that.... but i need now to fix the plugin....Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mageplaza\CallForPrice\Helper\Data::isEnabled() in /var/www/vhosts/nedeias.ro/public_html/app/code/Mageplaza/CallForPrice/Observer/CallForPriceLayoutLoadBefore.php:67

Comment: This may be another ques, better to create another ques. Based on the error, it looks like isEnabled() method is not available in Data.php, you can contact Mageplaza team further if it is their module. If isEnabled() method not available then add it Data.php.

Comment: @FurtunaAbel A bit late, but isEnabled is inherited from AbstractData in Mageplaza\Core, make sure you have the Core installed