# Magento 2 reindex error

Tags: php, apache

Magento 2.2. Please can anyone help with this I am trying to run this in CLI

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

```
Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in /home/redjohnco/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 420
```

I thought this issue would be bypass or resolved by switching from GD2 to ImageMagick

Comment: can you please make sure that the permissions are set correctly?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions/95033#95033

Comment: permission is set again but still issue remains

Comment: I had this before when a mage store ran out of disk space and some empty image files were created `find ./pub/media -type f -size 0` or `find ./pub/media -type f -empty`

Comment: thanks i came across similar comment to yours and will run this - can you let me know what you did to those images did you delete them if so what command did you use. Secondly I see in my /public_html/pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/default   there are 3 placeholder images  all are same size - b1.jpg b1._1jpg b1_2.jpg  200 x 112  should there be some more in here different sizes

Comment: Just got on FTP and deleted them. It was only 4 or 5 images. Sorry not sure about your placeholder query.

Comment: thanks i got some images in the output which i am deleting and will try reindex after can I please check was your store search set to elasticsearch - and did you have any problems on front end category pages with none or not all products appearing As i only got this error when changing to elasticsearch and trying to reindex before this when using mysql search i never had this error

Comment: I run the command to reindex now I am getting a similar error but with different line mentioned Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 890