# Display format of site and admin panel not working

Tags: css, format

I am pretty new to magento and was trying to update quantity from magento admin. Not sure what went wrong format, css stopped working. Nothing working on Magento Admin also. I can login to admin but when i try to click any button it goes in loop. I have attached screenshot please help here .enter image description here.

[image]

Comment: What mode are you runing magento? developer? production ? default? 
Deploy you static files if you are in the last 2, and fix your permission on files

Comment: Hey i am running it developer mode . I was downloading bulk data by export job and updated quantity for some items and suddenly site + magneto admin lost formatting and stopped working. Do i need to change developer mode to prod or default and then deploy static files?or i can deploy in development mode also?

Comment: if you are in develoepr mode then no, but i will consider looking at the file files permission and mb restarting your webserver

Comment: Which files permission?.htaccess.??

Comment: file permission :(
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Comment: if .htaccess is wrongly configured then this can be an error also :)

Comment: thanks for your reply

Comment: You manged to solve the issue ?:)