# Magento 2 specific folder permisson

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

I have the folder path /var/www/html/stagedesign/magento_root

How do I set folder permisson 777 to only stagedesign?

I have tried this in the stagedesign folder but nothing happened.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                       

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                      

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;               

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

I was looking at a few other examples but I couldn't find an answer to set the permissions to one folder.

I have been looking at these:

- [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Hosting-Performance/Folder-Permissions-for-magento2/td-p/110546
- https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-permissions-and-ownership.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the folder stagedesign and NOT what's under it, you should use

`sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/stagedesign`

You **must not** use the `-R` flag that will set all files and folder to 777 !

Bu it's rarely a good idea to set anything to 777

Answer (score 1):

Set 777 Permission stagedesign folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/www/html/stagedesign
```