# chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/magento/ SAFE?

Tags: permissions

to fix an issue in Magento I found this solution here on Stackexchange:

I used this command line in Putty:

So after that I could fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is help you may be try this :-

Use The following commands to set permissions, it may help

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;     
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;     
find ./media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;   
chmod 777 ./app/etc              
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Comment: I don't understand the commandos.
Could you explain it step by step?

Comment: Please refer this link fully explain :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the Magento permissions!