# Help! Dev Magento Site Down after Upgrading Module in EC2 instance on Server

Tags: magento2.3, error

Does any one no a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Make proper permissions to cache folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an permission issue.

Please refer below answer and set proper permissions to your magento project directory.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95033