# Is it safe to permission set 777 for var?

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

I saw 'Never use 777 for security reason' and I also found Magento 2 recommended permission setup on [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)

```
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Is it safe to use 777 for those and why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is recommended?

Where did you find this?

Refer the official documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html

Comment: I found it on 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Comment: That's the problem with the internet, don't believe everything with lots of upvotes.

Comment: I see..! I will not follow it entirely. Thanks!