# Magento 2.3.4 - Best practice to do update magento files and modules without affect the website in Production Mode

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.4, permissions, production-mode

If i update any modules or disable extensions my website showing an error message, i do following all the commands then coming back to normal,

1. rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
2. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f   // (-f for Development Mode)
4. php bin/magento cache:flush
5. Give permission

Time to complete a minimum of 5 minutes, during that time my website showing error message like

1. Permission related issue
2. Static files related issue

How to overcome this issue in the **Production Mode**?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to your server configuration.
You can set a default permission for new files and directories on your server.

Use the **umask** command to set the default permission.

If you want to set 777 permission for all the directories, run the following commands from the root directory of Magento

```
umask 0000
```

After running this command, whenever a new directory is created, it will assign 777 permission by default.

Please visit the following URL to get more idea about this command and how it works.

https://geek-university.com/linux/set-the-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files/

**Note:** It is not recommended to set the 777 permission by default. Once the development phase is over, make sure to revert the permissions for Magento files and directories as shown here :  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95033/48571

Comment: Now my website production mode.

Comment: If your website is in the production mode, then do not set the default permission. Instead, set the permission manually after running your commands.

Comment: Now i do the same job, during running the commands my website shows an error message on the website to the customers, how to handle this issue?

Comment: You have to update the ACL configuration on your server for setting the default permission on a specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the owner of the files,
 If it is the current user or not.
Check if below is the case.

```
$ ls -l /var/www/html/magento/
total 8 
drwxr-xr-x 2 sujit sujit 4096 Feb 21 23:39 ./ 
drwxr-x--- 5 rohan nobody 4096 Feb 22 02:28 ../
```

So below command can help:

`sudo chown -R myuser:mygroup <flile/directory name>`

Answer (score 0):

On a very basic level what I used to do is to keep 2 magento connected to same database. Run the commands on the one that is not connected to your domain currently, while the other folder remains untouched and live traffic doesn't feel anything. When you completely execute all the commands than u can either rename the folder names so that live domain can point to the magento folder in which you have run all the commands.

Off course you have to keep your media folder up to date manually or best approach in that case scenario is to create a subdomain for static contents so that you don't have to keep track of more than one media media folder.