# the "config.php" deployment config file isn't writable magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2

i try to install module after command run php bin/magento setup:upgrade error show
-> updating modules: *the "config.php" deployment config file isn't writable*
please can you help

Comment: Set required write permission to the app/etc folder. Check this for more details https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html#set-file-permissions

Comment: thank for reply can you give simply command, that is very complicated

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95033/84221

Comment: thank you @RahulBarot

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to set the correct permissions:

```
chmod 644 path/to/magento/app/etc/config.php
```

Answer (score -1):

Give permission to your magento2 package.

sudo chmod 777 -R magento2

where magento is your package inside /var/www/html