# sudo php bin/magento module:status didn't run?

Tags: php, database, magento2.4.6, php8.1

I was trying to run this command but the error raised like this

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/medical/bin/../app/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/medical/bin/magento on line 14
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/medical/bin/../app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/medical/bin/magento:14
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/medical/bin/magento on line 14
```

Please help me on this error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be files and folder permission issue. so give proper permission by follow this link [Magento 2 folder/file permissions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions) then try to run status command.

Answer (score 0):

**Please give the proper permission to the Magento folder and files.**

// 755 permission for directory

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;

// 644 permission for files

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chmod u+x bin/magento